# hive pareseexception while creating table from df

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am reading CSV file with spark and storing the DF as table in HIVE by using sparl JDBC Hive.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("PATH_TO_CSV");
df.write
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default")
.option("dbtable", "student2")
.option("user", "hive")
.option("password", "hive")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save;
```

I am getting below exception in spark shell and not sure why i am geting this exception

```
    org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:25 cannot recognize input near '"_c0"' 'TEXT' ',' in column name or primary key or foreign key
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:279)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:265)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:303)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:244)
at infoworks.tools.hive.HiveUtils.execStmts(HiveUtils.java:506)
at infoworks.tools.hive.HiveUtils.createHiveTable(HiveUtils.java:740)
```

Can anyone help why i am getting the above exception?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please also share the sample data that you are trying to insert into the HIVE table?